# Set div class to match its text

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to copy the text of a div to its class. I have got the code below but it copies text from all sibling div(s) but I want only current div's text to be its class.

Like the code below will copy "I am alex How are you" as a class for both divs below code, what I want the 1st div should only have class "I am alex" and likewise next class should only have a class "How are you" .

```
<div class="someText">I am alex</div>
<div class="someText">How are you</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
    var classes = $(".someText").text().replace(/[, -- .]/g," "); 
    $(".someText").addClass(classes);
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

It's a very odd requirement, but you can achieve it by passing a function to `addClass()`, like this:

```js
$('.someText').addClass(function() {
  return $(this).text();
});
```

```css
.am {
  color: blue;
}
.are {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="someText">I am alex</div>
<div class="someText">How are you</div>
```

Comment: Thanks bro! can you please also tell me how can I replace "," to no space same with "and" in the text.

Actually I am after this functionality, if you can help me with... 
http://codepen.io/desandro/pen/pJPwpy

Comment: `$(this).text().replace(',', '').replace('and', '');`. No problem, glad to help

Comment: no, and is replacing a,n and d from everywhere within the string.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to loop through each div.

```js
$(function() {
  $('div.someText').each(function() {
    var classes = $(this).text().replace(/[, -- .]/g, " ");
    $(this).addClass(classes);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="someText">I am alex</div>
<div class="someText">How are you</div>
```

Comment: thanks, how can I set data-filter=".value" for a  button same way?

Answer (score 0):

This what you wanted?

```js
var divs = $(".someText");
for (var i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) {
    $(divs[i]).addClass($(divs[i]).text().replace(/[, -- .]/g," "));
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="someText">I am alex</div>
 <div class="someText">How are you</div>
```